# Segue does not work after Facebook Login

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, segue

For some reason after the user logs in via facebook the segue that takes the user to the profile screen is never executed.

```
var permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]


PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, block: {

(user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

if user == nil {

NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")


} elseif user.isNew {

println("the user is new")

NSLog("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")

// THIS WORK
println("THE NEW USER FACEBOOK HAS LOGGED IN AND IS READY TO JUMP TO THE NEXT SCREEN")
//BUT THIS DOESN'T
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToSignUp", sender: self) 

} else {

NSLog("User logged in through Facebook!")



}

})
```

in the code above, this line never get executed:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpToSignUp", sender: self)
```

The user can login via fb, the record get stored in parse, but the it never jumps to the (next)sign up screen.
I have verified that the segue identifier is correct. The weird part is that there is no error in the logs.

any ideas, why this might be happening?

Comment: What does happen? Nothing? A crash? If you put another println statement after the performSegue line, does it print out?

Comment: I would assume that `PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions` performs on a background thread, so I would try performing the segue on the main queue.

Comment: still have not been able to solve, atwalsh04 - thank you still trying to figure it out.  @rdelmar yes i have a print statement right before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - my code is correct. The problem was the next screen. I had some IBOutlets that were not properly set up. I fixed it and it worked again. Just make sure that everything in your next screen is set up properly otherwise the segue will not work.

Comment: How did you discover/repair this? I'm having the same problem now; perfectly silent failure.

Comment: @AndresJaanTack click on the view controller and just go to the ib inspector on the right side  see all the properties are set up properly. Make sure that no properties have two outlets. Let me know if that helps.